# Ubuntu Translation, Confused (Key to give keyboard-focus to the Launcher)

Tags: unity, translation

What does it means "to give keyboard-focus to the Launcher". What is keyboard-focus and how can it be given to the launcher? And I don't understand "Gives keyboard-focus to the Launcher so it can be navigated with the cursor-keys." also.

And also, what is a "cursor-key"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a program has "keyboard focus", keys you press will be sent to that application.

So, if the Launcher has keyboard focus "so it can be navigated with the cursor-keys", that means that keys you press will interact with the launcher.

#### And also, what is a "cursor-key"?

The cursor keys are the up, down, left and right arrow keys. They're usually near the bottom right corner of a keyboard.

Comment: so if my application has the hot key "Alt + Shift + D", I need to first hit the keyboard focus?

Comment: @DanielCheung Keyboard focus is automatically given to the focused (active) application, so no.

Comment: ok, i understand now. so "the key i press would interact with the launch", are they just the application hot-keys particularly? the other key presses would react just normal tho the active application?

Comment: @DanielCheung See my edited answer about cursor keys.

Comment: Thanks, translating for ubuntu sure feels good, but when they just give you a sentence without description really is a pain to understand